# Get the active link to remain bold and not only become bold when I click on it

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am aware of both `:visited` and `:active` css classes, but both does not answer my need!

I want to remain the active link styled with **Red Background Color** (or whatever design) as long as the related page of the active link is active for the user.

**Below is my code:**

**HTML:**

```
<a class="link1" href="/page-1">Link 1</a>
<a class="link2" href="/page-2">Link 2</a>
<a class="link3" href="/page-3">Link 3</a>
<a class="link4" href="/page-4">Link 4</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
link2:visited {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Or

```
link2:active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

The `:active` class will take effect when the user click down the mouse button and end when the user will release up the mouse button.

The `:visited` class will remain the link with red background even after the user will click on another menu link.

so both `:visited` and `:active` css classes does answer my question !!!

**The below images will explain more:**

[Link 2 is active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dVUk.png)

[Link 4 is active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMMGi.jpg)

As you can see in the above images when another link on the menu is clicked/visited, the previous link design will be reverted back to its previous state and only the current clicked/visited link will have a red background color as long as its correspondent page is active.

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and put it in the question itself instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using jQuery and JavaScript as below:

```
(function ($, window, Drupal) {
$(window).ready(function () {
 // Get the current page url.
 var pathname = window.location.pathname;

    if (pathname == "/path1") {
      $('.link1').addClass("active-page");
    }

    if (pathname == "/path2") {
      $('.link2').addClass("active-page");
    }

    if (pathname == "/path3") {
      $('.link3').addClass("active-page");
    }

    if (pathname == "/path4" || pathname == "/") {
      $('.link4').addClass("active-page");
    }
});
})(jQuery, window, Drupal);
```

The above method is working as expected at least for me!

I still needs an advise if this could affect the site performance in a way or another ?

Answer (score 0):

we can use jquery to add class to each link when it is an active state. then we can style the link with the basis of that class.
checkout this link for reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_addclass.asp
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use javascript,

On each page, at the bottom, add:

```
<script>
    var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("link1");
    ele[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
<script>
```

change the class name for each page: link2 on page 2; link3 on page 3, etc.